# jre1.6.0_27 HashMap values() sourcecode

Tags: java, hashmap

Today, I opened jre1.6.0_27 HashMap values() method sourcecode

```
  389  public Set<K> keySet()
  390  {
  391      Set localSet = this.keySet;
  392      return (this.keySet = new KeySet(null));
  393  }
  394
  395  public Collection<V> values()
  396  {
  397      Collection localCollection = this.values;
  398      return (this.values = new Values(null));
  399  }
```

I think these sourcecode are error, but I don't know why they look like this.
Who can tell me why?

=======================================

Thanks everyone,
I think this is Eclipse problem, this sourcecode I used Eclipse F3 and went to it, so it looks like the above that.

I just open src.zip, this method sourcecode is right.

```
/**
 * Returns a {@link Collection} view of the values contained in this map.
 * The collection is backed by the map, so changes to the map are
 * reflected in the collection, and vice-versa.  If the map is
 * modified while an iteration over the collection is in progress
 * (except through the iterator's own <tt>remove</tt> operation),
 * the results of the iteration are undefined.  The collection
 * supports element removal, which removes the corresponding
 * mapping from the map, via the <tt>Iterator.remove</tt>,
 * <tt>Collection.remove</tt>, <tt>removeAll</tt>,
 * <tt>retainAll</tt> and <tt>clear</tt> operations.  It does not
 * support the <tt>add</tt> or <tt>addAll</tt> operations.
 */
903    public Collection<V> values() {
904        Collection<V> vs = values;
905        return (vs != null ? vs : (values = new Values()));
906    }
```

Comment: Can you articulate what you think is wrong?  The fact that it's in the source code tells you that it's likely to be correct, especially since HashMap has been part of the JRE since 1995.  The changes make it compatible with generics.

Comment: Seems like you discover a bug in code.

Comment: These methods are called and used all over the world, millions times a day by thousands of software systems, and nobody seems to have a problem with them. And now you think they are wrong?

Comment: well at least the example above will return an empty Collection...

Comment: @dngfng Without knowing what exactly the classes `KeySet` and `Values` are, you don't know if these methods actually return empty collections.

Answer (score 0):

At least in OpenJDK 7 it looks correct:

```
  880       public Set<K> keySet() {
  881           Set<K> ks = keySet;
  882           return (ks != null ? ks : (keySet = new KeySet()));
  883       }

  916       public Collection<V> values() {
  917           Collection<V> vs = values;
  918           return (vs != null ? vs : (values = new Values()));
  919       }
```

Comment: This is as it appears in the jdk1.6.0_27 source as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think these methods are wrong? You have to look at the source code of the inner classes `KeySet` and `Values` inside `HashMap` to understand how these work.

The `keySet()` method returns a new `KeySet` object. In JDK 1.6.0_35, the source code of the inner class `KeySet` looks like this:

```
private final class KeySet extends AbstractSet<K> {
    public Iterator<K> iterator() {
        return newKeyIterator();
    }
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return containsKey(o);
    }
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return HashMap.this.removeEntryForKey(o) != null;
    }
    public void clear() {
        HashMap.this.clear();
    }
}
```

It's an implementation of `Set` that gets its data from the `HashMap`.

Likewise there's an inner class `Values` that works in the same way.

Comment: @TimBender No, you just don't understand how it works... Study the complete source code of `HashMap` and its superclass `AbstractMap` if you want to know exactly. Especially look at the member variables `keySet` and `values` in `AbstractMap`. They are **not** the fields that holds the map's data. They are just cache variables, to avoid creating unnecessary extra objects.

Comment: Your right on that, but it still stands that the code posted by the OP is erroneous. The JDK doesn't re-create an instance of `Values` if it can be avoided.